# Python code works in Spyder but not when triggered via batch file

Tags: python, batch-file

I have written a little Python program that pulls data from a weather forecast API for 4 specific locations and saves the resulting dicts in 4 separate txt files.
This works without any problems if I run the code from spyder. The txt files appear in the folder where the .py fole is located.
Now I want to use "Task Scheduler" to run the script every hour. To do so I prepared a batch file:

```
@echo off
cd C:\Users\MyName\Documents\API_Meteo
call C:\Users\MyName\anaconda3\Scripts\activate
C:\Users\MyName\anaconda3\python.exe 
python 0DR-RISE_Meteo.py
pause
```

I call this file via the Task Scheduler and it opens the cmd. But it does not seem to run the program as all I see is this:
[image]

Cheers for your help!!

Axel

Comment: Line 4. is not a command on its own like that. What happens if you change it to ```C:\Users\MyName\anaconda3\python.exe 0DR-RISE_Meteo.py```, then remove line 5. ```python 0DR-RISE_Meteo.py```?